# HAC,HMC login issue in hybris 5.7

Tags: spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

During migration from hybris 5.5 to hybris 5.7 after doing login in hmc and hac getting a error page with some error details on it.

LOG details:

de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloSystemException: cannot find password encoder for encoding 'plain'[HY--1] at de.hybris.platform.ldap.jalo.security.user.LDAPUserPasswordCheckingStrategy.checkPassword(LDAPUserPasswordCheckingStrategy.java:59) at de.hybris.platform.jalo.user.UserManager.checkPassword(UserManager.java:1670) at de.hybris.platform.jalo.user.User.checkPassword(User.java:565) at de.hybris.platform.jalo.user.User.checkPassword(User.java:541) at de.hybris.platform.spring.security.CoreAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CoreAuthenticationProvider.java:130) at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156) at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:256) at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$StatisticsGatewayFilter.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:345) at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226) at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SecureMediaFilter.doFilter(SecureMediaFilter.java:97) at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226) at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.DataSourceSwitchingFilter.doFilter(DataSourceSwitchingFilter.java:73) at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226) at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:73) at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226) at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.RedirectWhenSystemIsNotInitializedFilter.doFilter(RedirectWhenSystemIsNotInitializedFilter.java:104) at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226) at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:47) at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226) at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:156) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:230) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: de.hybris.platform.jalo.security.PasswordEncoderNotFoundException: cannot find password encoder for encoding 'plain'[HY-0] at de.hybris.platform.persistence.security.PasswordEncoderFactoryImpl.getEncoder(PasswordEncoderFactoryImpl.java:145) at de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloConnection.getPasswordEncoder(JaloConnection.java:1048) at de.hybris.platform.jalo.user.DefaultUserPasswordCheckingStrategy.checkPassword(DefaultUserPasswordCheckingStrategy.java:24) at de.hybris.platform.ldap.jalo.security.user.LDAPUserPasswordCheckingStrategy.checkPassword(LDAPUserPasswordCheckingStrategy.java:45) ... 72 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an hybris 5.7 but you should configure something like that in core-spring.xml of platform:

```
<bean id="core.passwordEncoderFactory" class="de.hybris.platform.persistence.security.PasswordEncoderFactoryImpl">
    <property name="encoders">
        <map>
            <entry key="*" value-ref="${default.password.encoder}" />
            <entry key="plain" value-ref="core.plainTextEncoder" />
            <entry key="sha-256" value-ref="sha256PasswordEncoder" />
            <entry key="sha-512" value-ref="sha512PasswordEncoder" />
            <entry key="md5" value-ref="core.saltedMD5PasswordEncoder" />
            <entry key="pbkdf2" value-ref="pbkdf2PasswordEncoder" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="core.plainTextEncoder" class="de.hybris.platform.persistence.security.PlainTextPasswordEncoder" />
```

If that's not the case then override the bean definition to add the "plain" property and the reference to the plain encoder.

Comment: I am facing this same issue as well. But in my case in the core-spring.xml the entry for "plain" is already included and defined properly. Still have issue though

Comment: @tony I guess in this case it's not the bean you're looking that is loaded or used. Check that both `core.passwordEncoderFactory` and `core.plainTextEncoder` are well defined and if they are not overriden somewhere. Or maybe you have some Spring errors when hybris starts?